# Error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: ....linker problem

Tags: c

I'm trying to put a function from file operations.c into the main file. I wrote the header file for it and declared his include in the main file, but now it appears I have some problem with the linker.

Main file (`trials.c`):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include "operations.h"


int main()
{

  menuDifInt();

  return 0;
 }
```

The `operations.c` file which has the function code:

```
 void menuDifInt()
 {
 }
```

And finally the header file for operations (`operations.h`):

```
 #ifndef OPERATIONS_H
 #define OPERATIONS_H

 double trapezoidalrule();
 double fsquare(double x);
 void menuDifInt();

 #endif
```

I use this commands to compile:

```
$ gcc trials.c
```

And the error that appears is:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_menuDifInt", referenced from:
  _main in trials-045b92.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Add the commands used to compile.

Comment: I used these commands to compile:

  $gcc trials.c
and

  $./a.out Is this what you mean?

Comment: You never actually compile the file that has the symbols that are missing. For a simple solution, add your second source file to the `gcc` command.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. You should edit the question to include those, they are important information. Check my answer.

Comment: Also, don't forget to `#include operations.h` in operations.c

Comment: OT:  when writing prototypes for functions, as you have done in the `operations.h` file, when those function do not receive any parameters, always place `void` between the parens, so the compiler produces code that does not expect any parameter(s) rather than produces code that expects any number of parameters.  I.E. `double trapezoidalrule( void );
 double fsquare(double x);
 void menuDifInt( void );`

Comment: strongly suggest, when compiling to always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The following gcc compiler options are minimal: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversions -pedantic -std-gnu11`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I used these commands to compile: $gcc trials.c and $./a.out

You don't give the compiler any information about where `menuDifInt` is defined. You also have to pass the `.c` file where the function is defined. Simply doing `#include "operations.h"` does not automatically add `operations.c` to the files to compile.

Compile your code with:

```
$ gcc trials.c operations.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the C files together:

```
clang -o trials trials.c operations.c
```

Add any compiler flags you want.

Check out build tools, like make, to simplify/automatize building for when it gets more complex.